# KQL multiple aggregates in a summarize statement

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have data in a table for azure data explorer, let's say the following columns:

> Day, non-unique-ID, Message-Content

What I want as an output is a table containing:

> Day, Count of records per day, distinct Count of non-unique-ID per day

I know how to get one or the other:

`summarize count() by Day`

`summarize dcount(non-unique-ID) by Day`

but I don't know how to get a table containing both of those columns, because `summarize` will only let me run a single aggregate query per command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple aggregation functions in the same `summarize` operator, all you have to do is separate them with commas. So this will work:

`summarize count(), dcount(non-unique-ID) by Day`

Comment: Excellent, thanks. The key thing I missed was that you only need to specify `by Day` once